# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$11: (vector) => vector)

Tags: pyspark

both of the train data and the test data have 52 features ,,have the same dimention .The way of extracting features are the same.The program has no syntax errors.When i added a random sampling of negative samples,the error occurred.
please，give me a help,thanks

Comment: sorry,this is terrible problem,i will commit another with detail.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that you are using a vector indexer in your pipeline and you would not have provided the maxcategories argument. So if you are in Pysaprk it would look something like

```
featureIndexer =\
    VectorIndexer(inputCol="features", outputCol="indexedFeatures", maxCategories=2)
```

The issue is that one of your columns might be a continuous variable and the indexer took it as categorical. Or the data was categorical but the indexer did not see all the categories in training data.

The default value of maxcategories is 20 . You can refer the documentation here https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.feature.VectorIndexer